# angular testing multiple files in sequence - Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

Started with Angular E2E, and tried to test multiple files (divided the test cases module wise).

Changes made in **protractor.conf.js**

```
specs: [
     "./src/login/login.component.e2e-spec.ts",
     "./src/customs-portal/home.component.e2e-spec.ts",
],
```

this runs the test cases of both files in the same sequence.

In the home test case file I have written

```
beforeAll(() => {
     homePage= new HomePage();
     helperService = new HelperService();

     CSS = homePage.CSS;
     helperService.navigate("/home");

     helperService.skipIntro();
});
```

i navigate to **/home**, on home page there is **skip** button that i clicks to avoid intro phase about the page. Here is how skipIntro function looks like

```
async skipIntro(): Promise<any> {
    const _skipBtn = await element(by.css(this.CSS.SKIP_INTRO));
    console.log("HelperService -> _skipBtn", _skipBtn);
    if (_skipBtn) {
        _skipBtn.click();
    }
}
```

but it shows error and fails the test case

```
it("dummy test always paas", async () => {
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
});
```

here is the error

```
- Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

here is helperService.navigate

```
navigate(path: string): promise.Promise<any> {
        return browser.get(path);
}
```

any help on this, not much experience on Angular E2E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should work

```
     beforeAll(async () => {
     homePage= new HomePage();
     helperService = new HelperService();
     CSS = homePage.CSS;

    await helperService.navigate("/home");
    await  helperService.skipIntro();
});

async skipIntro(): Promise<any> {
 const _skipBtn =await element(by.css(this.CSS.SKIP_INTRO));
    console.log("HelperService -> _skipBtn", _skipBtn);
    if (_skipBtn) {
        await _skipBtn.click();
    }
}

async navigate(path: string): promise.Promise<any> {
        await return browser.get(path);
}

async skipIntro(): Promise<any> {
    const _skipBtn = await element(by.css(this.CSS.SKIP_INTRO));
    console.log("HelperService -> _skipBtn", _skipBtn);
    if (_skipBtn) {
        await _skipBtn.click();
    }
}

async navigate(path: string): promise.Promise<any> {
        await return browser.get(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error, I am assuming that the application under test is not `Angular` application. Protractor is mostly used to test angular applications but to test `non-angular` applications you can do following configuration change and you probably won't get this error

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

This will disable searching for angular components in application and tests will get executed.

Comment: App is on angular 9.

Comment: Ok.. What is `helperService.navigate()` implementaion? Is it using `browser.navigate("url")` to open the application?

Comment: `return browser.get(path);` this i am using, edited the question as well

Answer (score -1):

seems like async and control flow is mixed that seems to be an issue